# Selecting date an item was ordered SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have the following tables:

- Order (orderID, date, shipID)
- Shipping (shipID, price)
- PO (prodID, orderID, amount)
- Price (prodID, fromDate, price)

I need to retrieve each order ID and the total price including the cost of the items in order + the cost of shipping purchased. The cost of the item has to be the cost of the item on the order date, not the most recent date. The Price table stores the different prices of a product starting at a particular date (fromDate attribute). Hence, the price of a product on day d is the price in the entry with the largest fromDate-value f such that f ≤ d. The code I have does not return all orderIDs, only some. Any ideas?

```
SELECT o.orderId, SUM(pr.price) + SUM(s.price) orderCost
FROM [Order] o 
INNER JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 price, prodID FROM Price pr WHERE 
        fromDate <= (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM [Order])
     ) pr ON pr.prodID  = po.prodID
GROUP BY  o.orderId;

SELECT "Order".orderId
FROM "Order"
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data - what you have and what you expect to get. Cheers!

Comment: Are you really using MySQL? This looks like SQL Server to me.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . Why did you delete your answer?  You should just preface it with "I assume this is really SQL Server based on the syntax."

Comment: @gordon OP seems to be asking same question like 10 times, no effort shown.

Comment: @SalmanA . . . If you had left a comment, I would not have answered.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect some of your items don't have `shipping cost`, use `left join` instead.

```
SELECT o.orderId, SUM(coalesce(pr.price, 0)) + SUM(coalesce(s.price, 0)) orderCost
FROM [Order] o 
LEFT JOIN Shipping s ON o.shipId = s.shipId
INNER JOIN PO po ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 price, prodID FROM Price pr WHERE 
        fromDate <= (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM [Order])
     ) pr ON pr.prodID  = po.prodID
GROUP BY  o.orderId;
```

Answer (score 0):

In either SQL Server or MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery.  The exact syntax is a little different.  This uses SQL Server conventions, because that is consistent with the code in your question:

```
SELECT orderId, SUM(price) + SUM(price) as orderCost
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             (SELECT TOP (1) p.Price
              FROM Price p
              WHERE p.prodID = po.prodID AND
                    p.date <= o.date
              ORDER BY p.date DESC
             ) as price
      FROM [Order] o INNER JOIN
           Shipping s
           ON o.shipId = s.shipId INNER JOIN
           PO po
           ON o.orderId = po.orderId 
     ) o
GROUP BY orderId;
```